# webr::PieDonut used in my (R) function does only plot the donut, but not the pie. Any suggestions on how to solve my problem?

Tags: r

webr::PieDonut used in my (R) function does only plot the donut, but not the pie. Any suggestions on how to solve my problem?

This is the output of my function:
[image: Displays only the donut]

This is how it sould look like:
[image: Displayed correctly]

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: It's not clear what help we can offer given the information you have provided. Presumably there is a problem with either your data or with the code you are using on your data, but we don't have either of these. It's therefore not possible for us to reproduce your problem let alone fix it. Please make your question reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The solution is put less letters in the word of your varible that you put in the pie. I hope that this work for you.

Regards.